# Determine if folder ACL was modified since specific date in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, time, acl, last-modified

I need to determine if folder ACL was modified since specific date.
Does Windows store this type of information?

FileSystemInfo provides property LastWriteTime but when I change permissions on directory this date is not changing.

Is there any way to get this information?

Regards,
Jack.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? As a performance optimization? You could get the current value and compare it to a known old value for some applications.

Comment: Yes it's a performance optimization. Ineed to check large amount of folders periodically for permission changes. I would like to skip those which were not change since last check.

Answer (score 0):

The lower-level NT API exposes a field named ChangedTime in the [FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545762.aspx) structure; it is described as:

> Specifies the last time the file was changed.

It is essentially a time-stamp of when *any* of the meta-data (which I assume includes the security descriptor) was last modified.  Of course you can't tell *what* was changed that caused the time-stamp to be updated, but I think that's the best you can do out of the box.

There is also the [USN Journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798.aspx), but I believe this feature is disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for Your advice. Unfortunately the value of this field is not changing after ACL modification. Neither after read-only change.